# Given some rounded numbers, how to find the original fraction?

Tags: algorithms, integers

I have a small list of positive numbers rounded to (say) two decimals:

```
 1.15  (can be  1.145 -  1.154999...)
 1.92  (can be  1.915 -  1.924999...)
 2.36  (can be  2.355 -  2.364999...)
 2.63  (can be  2.625 -  2.634999...)
 2.78  (can be  2.775 -  2.784999...)
 3.14  (can be  3.135 -  3.144999...)
24.04  (can be 24.035 - 24.044999...)
```

I suspect that these numbers are fractions of integers and that all numerators *or* all denominators are equal. Choosing $100$ as a common denominator would work in this case, that would leave the last value as $\frac{2404}{100}$. But there could be a 'simpler' solution with much smaller integers.

How do I efficiently find the smallest common numerator and/or denominator? Or (if that is different) the one that would result in the smallest maximum denominator resp. numerator?

Of course I could brute force for small lists/numbers and few decimals. That would find $\frac{83}{72}$, $\frac{138}{72}$, $\frac{170}{72}$, $\frac{189}{72}$, $\frac{200}{72}$, $\frac{226}{72}$ and $\frac{1731}{72}$ for this example.

Comment: for each number do just a few steps in its continued fraction.

Comment: @WillJagy: That is the best solution for each individual number. But the OP is looking for the least common denominator of all the numbers.